# Installing Mysql 8 on a Raspberry Pi 3 B+

Tags: mysql

Has anyone had success installing Mysql 8 on a RPI?  Mysql 8 has json_table function and I would love to use that to insert records in bulk.

I have looked around but cannot find a mysql 8 installer for debian arm.

Comment: What exactly is your question.  `mysql-server` will install mariaDB on Stretch. If you want the latest version you are using the wrong OS as Debian is very conservative, so you will need to install from some external source.

Comment: Note that the version of MariaDB available in the current Raspbian distribution also supports JSON tables so you don't need MySQL to use this feature https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/connect-json-table-type/

Comment: MariaDB may have JSON table support but it does not have the JSON_TABLE function.  This function is available in Mysql 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common -y
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lars-tangvald/mysql-8.0
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

It consumes more memory than MySQL 5
SWAP required.

Since the authentication method has also been changed, please edit the following.
sudo vi /etc/mysql/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
```

Comment: You don't need change authentication. You need update your users|passwords.  It is not good information and it is also bad practice.

Comment: seems this does not work anymore:  add-apt-repository ppa:lars-tangvald/mysql-8.0 gives "could not find a distribution template for Raspbian/stretch"

Comment: It worked for Ubuntu Server but installed 5.7